# Some activities show with ".kt" and some without it

Tags: android-activity, kotlin

I was wondering if someone else have this.

I have created an app in kotlin, everything is working great but I realized that some of my activities are displayed differend in left panel from the others and I dunno why:

[image]

Also in it is marked as wrong in my code view:

[image]

However my app is working, including this activity. It is already added in the manifest and everything, is just that I'm curious about it.

I have like 7 activities, and have 3 of those like that, even thou all of theme were created the same way.

Any idea how can I fix this?

Regards

P.D.

I already checked the following:

In manifest:

```
        <activity android:name=".mty" />
```

at mty activity:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_mty.*
```

at layout:

```
    tools:context=".mty">
```

Comment: This is a Kotlin file, and Kotlin does not require 1 class per file unlike Java.

Comment: ok I understand that, but when I'm typing the intent code, for opening the activity, it is not displayed in the options for me to select it, and also it is marked in red as if AS couldn't find it. I created the other activities the very same way and they kept their format.

Comment: Name of kotlin file bears no relation to its content, you can have empty files and even cram entire project inside a single file. Unless you post files content it's impossible to tell what it does.

Comment: From the icons, you can infer MainActivity is a kotlin class and another one mty.kt is a kotlin file. Kotlin files can have multiple classes and they can have names irrespective of the file name. So mty.kt may not have a class named mty inside it.

Comment: @GaboWalker try this add two new Kotlin items to a project the first one use the word File in the little drop down. When you add the second one use the word Class in the little drop down. Guess MainActivity gets a Class type when you let Android Studio create that empty Activity